# I am trying to write a code for something similar to hangman, but it is not working

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to code a hangman kind of thing but even after the word is guessed correctly the loop continues.
It seems like the bit that isn't working is the `if word == ("".join(userword))` bit at the end, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong   .

```
import random
word = random.choice(["apple", "orange", "pineapple"])
word = list(word)
life = 5
userword = []

for i in range (len(word)):
    userword.append("_")

while life > 0: 
    print("".join(userword))
    print("enter a letter")
    letter = input()
    letterinword = False
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            userword[i] = letter
            letterinword = True

    if letterinword == False:
        life = life - 1

    if word == ("".join(userword)):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because "word" is converted to a list on line 3.

So you're comparing

```
['a','p','p','l','e'] == 'apple'
```

simplest fix is

```
if "".join(word) == "".join(userword):
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the randomly selected word to a list:

```
word = random.choice(["apple", "orange", "pineapple"])
word = list(word)
```

Remove the second line above and your exit clause will work.